# How to add quote icon in Bootstrap glyphicons?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I guess the titles tells it all.  The quote icon is absent in glyphicon icon set in bootstrap 3 which I'm using.
I know that I can use a separate image but it would mean an extra request being made and also the image will not be vectorial. so I'm wondering maybe there is a more elegant way to do so?

Answer (score 11):

```css
blockquote {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border-left: 10px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1.5em 10px;
  padding: 0.5em 10px;
  quotes: "\201C""\201D""\2018""\2019";
}

blockquote:before {
  color: #ccc;
  content: open-quote;
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 0.1em;
  margin-right: 0.25em;
  vertical-align: -0.4em;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>I'm quoted</blockquote>
```

Comment: It's nice, but my question is about quote `icon` not styling quote output.

Comment: Very nice. But don't forget to CLOSE the quotes too, otherwise from the second quote on you will see single quotes only. Here is how: `blockquote:after{ content: no-close-quote; }`

Answer (score 3):

Try using Font-Awesome http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/ it has qoutes.

Download and implement it in your project, when your done implementing it you can use it like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-quote-left"><i>I'm quoted!<i class="fa fa-quote-right"><i>
```

Comment: I know, but I already use glyphicon elsewhere on the project and I'd rather like to stick to it.

Comment: glyphicon have no quote unless if they will add new glyphs in newer versions.